# Stopping a task in shell script if logs contain specific string

Tags: shell, zsh, stdout

I am trying to run a command in shell script and would like to exit it if the processing logs (not sure what you call the logs that are outputted on terminal while the task is running) contains the string "INFO | Next session will start at"

I tried using grep but because the string "INFO | Next session will start at" is not in a stdout it does not detect while the command is running.

The specific command I'm running is below

```
pipenv run python3 run.py --config accounts/user/config.yml
```

By 'processing logs' I mean the log output before the stdout is displayed in the terminal.

```
...
[D 211127 10:07:12 init:400] atx-agent version 0.10.0
[D 211127 10:07:12 init:403] device wlan ip: route ip+net: no such network interface
[11/27 10:07:12]     INFO | Time delta has set to 00:11:51.
[11/27 10:07:13]     INFO | Kill atx agent.
[11/27 09:59:32]     INFO | Next session will start at: 10:28:30 (2021/11/27).
[11/27 09:59:32]     INFO | Time left: 00:28:57.
```

I am trying to do this because the yml file I'm trying to run has a limit on what time you can execute it, and I would like to exit the task if the time is not met.

I tried to give as much context but if there's something missing please let me know.

Comment: What version of bash, specifically? Or do you strictly require an answer that works in _both_ bash and zsh (which significantly constricts the features that can be used)?

Comment: Sorry using only zsh. And the version is zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)

Comment: Take out the bash tag if you won't accept bash-only answers. bash and zsh are two different shells, and they're very much not mutually compatible.

Comment: (I don't know what zsh's equivalent to bash coprocesses is, by the way, but it's one place to look. And if zsh lets you get the PID of a process substitution so you can kill the program inside one after reading from it, that's another general approach; but I only know the details for bash).

Comment: Does the output go to stdout or to stderr?

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
pipenv run python3 run.py --config accounts/user/config.yml |
sed "/INFO | Next session will start at/q"
```

`sed` prints the piped input, until it matches the expression and quits (`q`). The program will receive SIGPIPE (broken pipe) when it tries to continue writing, and (likely) exit. It's the same as what happens when you do something like `find | head`.

You could also use `kill` in a shell wrapper:

```
sh -c 'pipenv run python3 run.py --config accounts/user/config.yml |
{ sed "/INFO | Next session will start at/q"; kill -- -$$; }'
```

Notes:

- The program may print a different log if stdout is not a terminal.
- If you want to match a literal string, you could use `grep -Fm 1 PATTERN`, but other log output will be hidden. `grep` fails if no match, which can be useful.
- This will work any shell, including `zsh`. zsh or bash can also be used for the `kill` wrapper.
- There are other approaches. This thread focuses on `tail`, but is a useful reference: https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found